# How to add attribute to first P tag using PHP regular expression?

Tags: php, html, regex

WordPress spits posts in this format:

```
<h2>Some header</h>
<p>First paragraph of the post</p>
<p>Second paragraph of the post</p>
etc.
```

To get my cool styling on the first paragraph (it's one of those things that looks good only sparingly) I need to hook into the get_posts function to filter its output with a preg_replace.

The goal is to get the above code to look like:

```
<h2>Some header</h>
<p class="first">First paragraph of the post</p>
<p>Second paragraph of the post</p>
```

I have this so far but it's not even working (the error is: "preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier ']'")

```
$output=preg_replace('<p[^>]*>', '<p class="first">', $content);
```

I can't use CSS3 meta-selectors because I need to support IE6, and I can't apply the :first-line meta-selector (this is one that IE6 supports) on the parent container because it would hit the H2 instead of the first P.

Comment: Umm, am I missing something or could you just change the page template to hardcode the class attribute instead of hooking into `get_posts`

Comment: Can't because the P tags aren't created by the template, they are spit out by wordpress which runs the_content through the autop hook, thereby generating the P's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the answers there are some that will work but all have drawbacks of either using an external parsing library or possibly matching tags other than the P tag or also matching its attributes.

I ended up using this solution with the str_replace_once function from [here](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/21334-str_replace-only-once-occurence-only.html#post109511):

```
str_replace_once('<p>', '<p class="first">', $content);
```

Simple enough and it works just as intended. Here's full WordPress code snippet to filter the first paragraph any time the_content() is called:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'first_p_style');
function first_p_style($content) {
 $output=str_replace_once('<p>', '<p class="first">', $content);
 return ($output);
}
```

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 6):

You may find it easier and more reliable to use an HTML parser such as [this one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). HTML is notoriously difficult to parse reliably (technically, impossible) with regular expressions, and the parser will give you a very simple means to find the nodes you're interested in. The first page of [the doc](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) has a tab labelled "How to modify HTML elements".

Answer (score 3):

**Two right possibilities :**

1. Do that in Javascript. Using [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery), for example, it's a matter of one line : `$("h2").next().addClass("first")`
2. Use an [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Indeed, [regexp are not a good tool to do what you want to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Since loading a whole HTML parser for just this purpose is overkill, you'd really better be using Javascript.

**The wrong way**

Of course, in order to anwser the question, here is the best way I can't think of to make it happends with regexp. Though, I don't recommend it.

```
preg_replace('#(</h2>\s*<p[^>]*)>#im', '$1 class="first">', '<h2>Some header</h> <p>First paragraph of the post</p> <p>Second paragraph of the post</p> ');
```

What we do is:

- using preg_replace so we can use advanced regexp to replace the code;
- using "m" and "i" flag so the regexp does not bother about line break or case;
- using `</h2>\s*` to match the closing "h2" tags and all the spaces/line breaks after;
- using `*<p[^>]*` to match the "p" tag and its current attributs;
- using parenthesis to save that;
- using "$1" to replace to replace the matched string we the part we save;
- adding the class and closing the ">".

The first draw back I can think of is that it doesn't handle the case where a class already exists.

Of, and by the way, you have `<h2>...</h>` instead of `<h2>...</h2>`. I don't know if it's a typo but I assumed it was. Replace in the regexp accordingly if it's not.

Comment: Woops! Yeah the <h2>...</h> is a typo. I don't have to worry about malformed HTML since the blog engine is generating it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first character of the regex in a `preg_*` function is taken as a modifier delimiter. What you'd need is something like:

```
$output = preg_replace('~<p\b([^>]*)>~', '<p class="first" \1>', $content, 1);
```

This also puts back any extra attributes the `<p>` may have.

Overall, though, it's cleaner to do with CSS selectors and a JS fallback for IE.

**EDIT:** Added replacement limit and word break.

Answer (score 1):

in this particular case regexp solution would be fairly easy

```
echo preg_replace('~</h2>\s*<p~', "$0 class='first'", $html);
```